# Dynamically add select fields Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model whose values are linked by a many-many field

```py
class Structure(models.Model):
    structure_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    drawings = models.ManyToManyField(Drawing, related_name="structures")
```

I am trying to create a form that allows me to dynamically add structures and drawings, where each drawing must be from existing drawings.

With formsets I am able to create multiple forms for 1 structure 1 drawing, but I want to be able to have multiple drawing per structure

Goal is to display the inputs in the following layout
[image: Final Input layout]

How do I create a form that allows me to add multiple drawings using select

Comment: Forms allow a prefix. You can include multiple forms of the same type if they all get a different prefix. You must also include this prefix when submitting the form.